# Google Chrome extension changing CSS in a specific page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am very new on Chrome extension development.

And this is my scnerio:

When user entered the specific page which is chosen by me. The extension add a CSS tag into a div.

The CSS tag is: text-transform: lowercase;

If there is a short tutorial for this I will pleased.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off adding it to the element style in chrome - it gives you a modified view of the area you have edited on the fly.

EDIT : To clarify, that is right clicking on the area you want to change and selecting "inspect element" then on the right hand side of the debug bar you will be able to enter "element styles"

Or course you should add the changed into the class or ID of it later on for release mode.

Comment: I found the class with "Inspect Element" as I say I am very new at this. Can you help me more?

Comment: That itself is not a class, double click on the {} in there and add your css to that area .. You will see the difference. for EX : background:#000000;

Comment: Understand now. But I want to make this wxtension.

Comment: So any changes you have made you can add to that class or ID of the div or area .. I hope i have explained as well as possible !